# Cannot get Scenebuilder to recognize my FXML annotated buttons

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

This app is a stopwatch game that has one of five images appear when you press start. My issue im having is I cannot get an image to appear in the ImageViewer, and I believe it is because When I try to put the id of the buttons and ImageViewer into the scenebuilder fx:id, it tells me that it does not exist, even though the spelling is correct. I have looked at tons of online resources and could not find any information.

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import java.io.File;


public class ClickController{

//creating the buttons
@FXML
private Button one;
@FXML
private Button two;
@FXML
private Button three;
@FXML
private Button four;
@FXML
private Button five;
@FXML
private Button start;
@FXML
private MenuItem close;
@FXML
private ImageView imgView;



Main main;
Stopwatch stopwatch;
boolean stopwatchactive = false;
boolean stopwatchrunning = false;
ArrayList<Image> imgList = new ArrayList<>();
Image firstImage = new Image("/images/1.png");
Image secondImage = new Image("/images/2.png");
Image thirdImage = new Image("/images/3.png");
Image fourthImage = new Image("/images/4.png");
Image fifthImage = new Image("/images/5.png");

@FXML
private void chooseImage(ActionEvent event){
    imgView.setImage(firstImage);
}


@FXML
private void oneButtonPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    imgView.setImage(firstImage);
    System.out.println("one");
    if(stopwatchrunning = true){
    stopwatch.stopTimer();
    stopwatchrunning = false;
    }
}

@FXML
private void twoButtonPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("two");
    if(stopwatchrunning = true){
        stopwatch.stopTimer();
        stopwatchrunning = false;
        }
}
@FXML
private void threeButtonPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("three");
    if(stopwatchrunning = true){
        stopwatch.stopTimer();
        stopwatchrunning = false;
        }
}
@FXML
private void fourButtonPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("four");
    if(stopwatchrunning = true){
        stopwatch.stopTimer();
        stopwatchrunning = false;
        }
}
@FXML
private void fiveButtonPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("five");
    if(stopwatchrunning = true){
        stopwatch.stopTimer();
        stopwatchrunning = false;
        }
}
@FXML
private void startButtonPush(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println("start");
    try{
        if(stopwatchactive != true){
            stopwatchactive = true;
            stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        }
        stopwatch.startTimer(); 
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
}

@FXML
private void closeButtonPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    stopwatchactive = false;
    stopwatch.logTimes();
    Platform.exit();
    System.exit(0);
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="application.ClickController">
<children>
  <Button fx:id="start" layoutX="271.0" layoutY="120.0" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#startButtonPush" text="Start" 
AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="253.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="271.0" 
AnchorPane.rightAnchor="270.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="120.0" />
  <Button fx:id="four" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" layoutX="382.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#fourButtonPush" text="four" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="97.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="382.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="159.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="276.0">
     <graphic>
        <ImageView>
           <image>
              <Image url="@../images/4.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </graphic>
  </Button>
  <Button fx:id="two" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" layoutX="155.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#twoButtonPush" text="two" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="97.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="155.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="386.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="276.0">
     <graphic>
        <ImageView>
           <image>
              <Image url="@../images/2.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </graphic>
  </Button>
  <Button fx:id="one" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#oneButtonPush" text="one" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="97.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="491.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="276.0">
     <graphic>
        <ImageView>
           <image>
              <Image url="@../images/1.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </graphic>
  </Button>
  <Button fx:id="three" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" layoutX="271.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#threeButtonPush" text="three" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="97.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="271.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="270.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="276.0">
     <graphic>
        <ImageView>
           <image>
              <Image url="@../images/3.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </graphic>
  </Button>
  <Button fx:id="five" contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY" layoutX="489.0" layoutY="276.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#fiveButtonPush" text="five" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="97.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="489.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="52.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="276.0">
     <graphic>
        <ImageView>
           <image>
              <Image url="@../images/5.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </graphic>
  </Button>
  <MenuBar>
    <menus>
      <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
        <items>
          <MenuItem fx:id="close" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeButtonPush" text="Close" />
        </items>
      </Menu>
    </menus>
  </MenuBar>
  <Label layoutX="191.0" layoutY="74.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="66.0" 
text="Cick on:" />
  <ImageView fx:id="imgView" fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="287.0" 
layoutY="58.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You did set the controller class???

Comment: Please post your fxml file… As @fabian suggested above, you have to tell the fxml file what its controller class is (and in which package it is).

Comment: update: I also have to change text in a label, but when I update the text that works? its only the image updating that seems to be an issue

Comment: i added full screen capability and now the images seem to appear, weird but atleast its fixed.

Comment: Might be that since the application is run from the compiled classes directory but the changes are done on the source fxml and the ide didn't detect the change from scenebuilder it will run an older version. But once a minor change is done in the code the files are re-synced.